# Attempt to store blob in iOS Safari 8 throws DataCloneError

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari, indexeddb

When I try to store a blob (retrieved via an `XMLHttpRequest` `GET` request, Safari on iOS 8.4 throws the error:

```
DataCloneError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 25: The data being stored could
not be cloned by the internal structured cloning algorithm
```

This happen with my code and also this example: http://robnyman.github.io/html5demos/indexeddb/

This is the line that cause my code (and the above example) to fail:

```
//This throws the error
var put = transaction.objectStore("elephants").put(blob, "image");
```

Is there a fix for this? Does the blob need to be base64 encoded first (like you had to do with WebSQL)?

**My CODE** *(works in Desktop Chrome/Firefox and Chrome/Firefox on Android):*

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var blob;

//Get the Video
xhr.open( "GET", "test.mp4", true );

//Set as blob
xhr.responseType = "blob";

//Listen for blob
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            blob = xhr.response;

            //Start transaction
            var transaction = db.transaction(["Videos"], "readwrite");

            //IT FAILS HERE
            var put = transaction.objectStore("Videos").put(blob, "savedvideo");

        }
        else {
            console.log("ERROR: Unable to download video." );
        }
}, false);

xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some *odd* reason (it's a bug), just like iOS Safari 7's WebSQL, you **cannot** store a BLOB in IndexedDB on iOS Safari 8. You have to convert it to base64 and then it will store without an error. (I repeat, this is a bug)

So, change the code to this:

**Change response type**

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

**Storing in database after retrieving from XMLHttpRequest**

```
//We'll make an array of unsigned ints to convert
var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
var i = uInt8Array.length;
var binaryString = new Array(i);
while (i--)
{
    //Convert each to character
    binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
}

//Make into a string
var data = binaryString.join('');

//Use built in btoa to make it a base64 encoded string
var base64 = window.btoa(data);

//Now we can save it
var transaction = db.transaction(["Videos"], "readwrite");
var put = transaction.objectStore("Videos").put(base64, "savedvideo");
```

**After retrieving form the IndexedDB, convert it back:**

```
//Convert back to bytes
var data = atob( event.target.result );

//Make back into unsigned array
var asArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);

for( var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i ) 
{
    //Get back as int
    asArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);    
}

//Make into a blob of proper type
var blob = new Blob( [ asArray.buffer ], {type: "video/mp4"} );

//Make into object url for video source
var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to get this into the record here. Did you come across any other StackOverflow issues that should be linked to here? Or issues at other StackExchange network sites?

Comment: Also, do you know if there is an open Safari/WebKit https://bugs.webkit.org/ bug for this? If not, please consider raising one. And regardless (if there is already one open or if instead you open one) it would be good to also link to that from here.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I did create a bug on Apple's bug database, not webkit, it's not a WebKit issue (works in Chrome from before they switched off WebKit) It's Safari's implementation that's wrong. I found a few other old questions from people possibly experiencing the same thing (not sure as their code was non-existent) but no answers.

Comment: Gave my +1. I worked around this by wrapping the db transaction in a try-catch. If the catch receives an error with `event.type === 25`, I do the base64 conversion before storing. Then just do a typecheck after retrieving it from idb and convert back to a blob if necessary (it's possible to just work with the base64 string in many use cases). This has been an issue for a long time and hopefully something Safari will fix as these are quite expensive operations...